# XPath: Get nodes where id contains a specific amount of letters

Tags: xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm using HTMLAgilityPack to retrieve data from a website.
The information I want is in `div` tags where their id is "solicitudesXXXXXX", where X are uppercase letters and there are always 6.

This is what I have so far

```
//div[contains(@id,'solicitudes']
```

Is there any function in XPath or anything else to specify the amount of letters I want the id to have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the IDs are always of the same length, you could actually just use the XPath function `starts-with()`:

```
//div[starts-with(@id, 'solicitudes')]
```

This will select all `div` elements with an `id` that starts with 'solicitudes'.  If you do need to select IDs that are of a certain length then you could do the following:

```
//div[starts-with(@id, 'solicitudes') and string-length(@id)=17]
```

Note: both `starts-with()` and `string-length()` are compatible with all versions of **XPath (1.0, 2.0 and 3.0)**.